# Spinor-helicity formalism, exact form of the spinors

Tags: field-theory, conventions, dirac-equation, spinors, helicity

I am trying to understand how to perform computations with the spinor helicity formalism, I am studying on [this review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697) by Elvang & Huang.

I have stumbled upon a problem though, in page 38 it is stated that

> Here we used the following convention for analytic continuation:
> $$|-p\rangle = - |p\rangle\qquad |-p] = + |p]. \tag{3.15}$$

I do not understand what this means.
Is there an arbitrariness in the definitions of the spinors that allows such a possibility? When I have tried to explicitly evaluate the spinors I obtained a different behaviour, the minus inside the spinor sign becomes an $i$ outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

$$p_{a\dot{b}}=-\left|p\right]_a\langle p|_{\dot{b}}$$

If you look into that equation, you should note that if you consider negative momentum, the expression becomes positive, because you only multiply by -1 in both sides. On the other hand, without multiplying, you can write the matrix expression for the -P matrix with the negative sign inside the brackets. Thus, you see that in order for both expressions to be equal, you have to choose one of the spinors with the negative sign inside to be equal to the one with positive sign while the other has to have the negative sign outside the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

1. Recall that the square and angle Weyl spinors in eq. (3.15) are defined via the positive and negative-frequency solutions $u_{\pm}(p)$ and $v_{\pm}(p)$ to the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) in momentum space, respectively, cf. eqs. (2.10-11).
2. In turn, the positive and negative-frequency solutions$^1$ $u_{\pm}(p)$ and $v_{\pm}(p)$ depend on a square root $\sqrt{p\cdot \sigma}$, and are hence in principle double-valued. However physicists usually pick a branch of the square root within the physical sector, in order for $u_{\pm}(p)$ and $v_{\pm}(p)$ to have a definite single-valued meaning, cf. e.g. Ref. 2.
3. As a consequence, the single-valued status is jeopardized when one analytically continue to the complex momentum space. In particular
   $$ - p\!\!/~=~|p\rangle [p| + |p]\langle p|\tag{2.15} $$ is a problem. The convention (3.15) should be viewed as an effort to save eq. (2.15).

References:

1. H. Elvang & Y.-t. Huang, *Scattering Amplitudes,* [arXiv:1308.1697](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697).
2. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT,* 1995; eq. (3.50).

--

$^1$ The subscript $\pm$ indicates the helicity $h = \pm 1/2$.